# IronPython keeps crashing on Compile() method. Not sure how to resolve

Tags: .net-core, ironpython

```
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(filePath, SourceCodeKind.File);
            var compiled = source.Compile();
            var result = source.Execute(scope);
```

The error I get is on **source.Compile()**

```
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ErrorListenerProxySink.Add(SourceUnit sourceUnit, String message, SourceSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Severity severity)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Int32 start, Int32 end, String message, Int32 errorCode)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Token t, IndexSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Boolean allowIncomplete)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(TokenWithSpan t, Int32 errorCode)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.EatNewLine()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSimpleStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFileWorker(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFile(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.ParseAndBindAst(CompilerContext context)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompilePythonCode(SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileSourceCode(SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Compile(CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Compile(ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.CompileInternal(CompilerOptions compilerOptions, ErrorListener errorListener)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Compile()
   at ReducedFareSystem.API.Helper.PythonScript.RunFromString() in PythonScript.cs:line 31
```

My Python script is designed to run with 0 parameter input and it generates a PDF.
I have run my Python script and it works fine from command line.

Comment: anyone have any input?

Answer (score 0):

I have been running a few python scripts before and I didn't need ScriptScope and Compile to execute my script.

```
            Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine pythonEngine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
            Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource pythonScript = pythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("pathto\file.py");
            pythonScript.Execute();
```

Try it like this maybe it may work without any errors?